# Sound at end of file

Tags: gedit

When looking at a file with gedit, is there a way to cause a sound e.g. a bell sound or a click when I reach the end of the file I am searching through?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18830/discussion-between-fabby-and-reluctant-linux-user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked all the gsettings of gedit and there isn't one...

You might try to do a "[Feature Request](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=gedit)"

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.*